# Test golang analyzer on production package usage

Tags: go, analysis, static-analysis

I have a module `errs` that defines a `MultiError` like so:

```golang
type MultiError []error
func NewMultiError(errs ...error) MultiError {}
// implementation omitted
```

I'd like to test a Go Analyzer to requires that a `MultiError` is always created by `errs.NewMultiError()` and never with a composite struct literal `errs.MultiError{}`. Writing the analyzer itself is straight-forward.

```golang
func run(pass *analysis.Pass) (interface{}, error) {
    for _, f := range pass.Files {
        ast.Inspect(f, func(n ast.Node) bool {
            if l, ok := n.(*ast.CompositeLit); ok {
                // Assume this does the right thing.
                return checkCompositeLit(l, pass)
            }
            return true
        })
    }
    return nil, nil
}
```

The approach I've tried is to create a source tree under `testdata` with a fake `errs` package. I'd prefer to use the real `errs` package but I can't figure out how:

Source tree:

```
.
├── multi_error.go
├── multi_error_test.go
└── testdata
    └── src
        ├── errs
        │   └── errs.go
        └── p
            └── p.go
```

But `analysistest` seems to do a partial package load, so I'm not able to depend on the stub `errs` package in package `p`.

```golang
// testdata/src/p/p.go
package p

import (
    "fmt"
)


func foo() {
    me := errs.MultiError{} // want `found MultiError created from struct literal; use errs.NewMultiError\(\) instead`
    me2 := errs.NewMultiError()

    fmt.Print(me, me2)
}
```

How do I test the analyzer? Is it possible to test using the real `errs` package instead of a stub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to add `import "errs"` to `testdata/src/p/p.go`. Then modify the patterns in analysistest.Run to include the packages under testdata, `errs` and `p`. analysistest will correctly wire up the packages.

```golang
func TestAll(t *testing.T) {
    analysistest.Run(t, analysistest.TestData(), Analyzer, "p", "errs")
}
```